# how i make connection to google app engine database in java

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am  making a web page which create user and a page from which user will login . i don't know how i connect to database of Google app engine in java .

if someone provide me any simple example or any link that would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Google App Engine database" is called Datastore. You can find the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/), and the API doc [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary.html).